# client receiving 500 (GoogleJsonResponseException) although app-engine endpoint server seems to work fine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

This bug is a bit of a mystery. I have a Google-Cloud-Endpoint method that returns `List<String>`. Just before exiting the method, I log the content of the string as

```
LOG.info(“list has: " + results);
```

And when I check on app-engine’s log, I see the printout.

Now on the android side I read the content as

```
StringCollection collection = service.getResults().execute();
```

According to android LogCat that very line is throwing an exception blaming the server of returning a 500 error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code": 500,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Internal Error",
      "reason": "internalError"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Internal Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.business.game.pack.ServerCall$2.doInBackground(ServerCall.java:189)
    at com.business.game.pack.ServerCall$2.doInBackground(ServerCall.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am not sure how to fix this error, as it seems to fall beyond my actual code.

Other attempts:

the endpoint used to return `CollectionResponse.<String> builder().setItems(results).build()`. I change it to simply `result` as troubleshooting but that didn’t help. So now the method signature (still failing) is

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getResults", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public List<String> getResults() {
    LOG.info(“Into  getResults");
    //… more code
    LOG.info(“list has: " + results);
    return results;// CollectionResponse.<String> builder().setItems(results).build();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check the content type is the same between two requests (application/json)

Comment: @DanOsipov I try to make sense of what you are saying but I don't get it. How might I do that?

Comment: Also the strings in the list are not derivatives. They are strings that the client sent to the datastore without any problem. Why didn't it throw a `GoogleJsonResponseException` then? And of course, as I said before, the server logs show the strings fine.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is quite crappy and I hope the google people resolve this. Evidently you cannot use String or a Collection of String as a return type. So that any of the following would fail:

```
return result;//String
return results;//List<String>
return CollectionResponse.<String> builder().setItems(results).build();
```

Instead you must create a wrapper that takes the string or collection thereof as field; a basic POJO.

This wasted a good 10hrs of my time. I hope it saves the next gal/guy some trouble.